# Rails-Api (4): Namespaced routes, only: actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-routing, rails-api

I am using the Rails-Api (4) and I want only three routes for my namespaced routes file.

In my routes.rb file, I am trying to do this:

```
namespace :api do
  namespace :v1 do
    resources :documents, only: [:get, :create]
    resource :system_status, only: [:get]        
  end
end
```

`rake routes` gets me only this:

```
          Prefix Verb URI Pattern                 Controller#Action
api_v1_documents POST /api/v1/documents(.:format) api/v1/documents#create
```

If a take the the `only:` off, it works and gives me all the routes (which I don't want).

I also tried this:

```
namespace :api do
  namespace :v1 do
    post '/documents',     to: 'documents#create'
    get  '/documents/:id', to: 'documents#show'
    get  '/system_status', to: 'system_status#show'    
  end
end
```

Gets me this odd output in `rake routes`:

```
              Prefix Verb URI Pattern                     Controller#Action
    api_v1_documents POST /api/v1/documents(.:format)     api/v1/documents#create
              api_v1 GET  /api/v1/documents/:id(.:format) api/v1/documents#show
api_v1_system_status GET  /api/v1/system_status(.:format) api/v1/system_status#show
```

Not sure what's up with `documents#show` getting me only `api_v1` as it's prefix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're getting mixed up between HTTP verbs and their corresponding Rails actions. There is no resource route for `:get`, but there are two routes for a GET request, which are `:index`, and `:show`

Change your original resource-based routing to this instead:

```
namespace :api do
  namespace :v1 do
    resources :documents, only: [:show, :create]
    resource :system_status, only: [:show]        
  end
end
```

And that should give you the proper routes, plus the correct URL helper prefixes.

Comment: @MichaelH. Happens to the best of us. Good luck! (Also, don't forget to accept the answer when you can)